# python adding number to string

Tags: python

Trying to add a count int to the end of a string *(website url)*:

Code:

```
  count = 0
  while count < 20:
    Url = "http://www.ihiphopmusic.com/music/page/" 
    Url = (Url) + (count)
    #Url = Url.append(count)
    print Url
```

I want:

```
http://www.ihiphopmusic.com/music/page/2
http://www.ihiphopmusic.com/music/page/3
http://www.ihiphopmusic.com/music/page/4
http://www.ihiphopmusic.com/music/page/5
```

Results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grub.py", line 7, in <module>
    Url = Url + (count)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Comment: Dude, use `url = <whatever>` instead of doing concatenation because in some forms of python (like Jython) you will incur massive overheads for string concats.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is exactly what the traceback states.
Python doesn't know what to do with `"hello" + 12345`

You'll have to convert the integer `count` into a string first.

Additionally, you never increment the `count` variable, so your while loop will go on forever.

Try something like this:

```
count = 0
url = "http://example.com/"
while count < 20:
    print(url + str(count))
    count += 1
```

Or even better:

```
url = "http://example.com/"
for count in range(1, 21):
    print(url + str(count))
```

As Just_another_dunce pointed out, in Python 2.x, you can also do

```
print url + str(count)
```

Comment: You should probably change that last count to an i

Comment: Quick comment, if python-2.7 is used, print is a statement and not a function

Comment: @Justanotherdunce: Yes I should include that, thanks. Regardless, I prefer to use `print()` for situations where the version is unspecified because it works in either case. Hence also my using `range()` instead of `xrange()`.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
 Url = (Url) + str(count)
```

instead. The problem was that you were trying to concatenate a *string* and a *number*, rather than two strings. [str()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str) will fix this for you.

`str()` will provide a string version of `count` suitable for concatenation, without actually converting `count` to a string from an int. See this example:

```
>>> n = 55

>>> str(n)
>>> '55'

>>> n
>>> 55
```

Lastly, it is considered more efficient to format a string, rather than concatenate it. I.e.,

```
 Url = '%s%d' % (Url, count)
```

or

```
 Url = '{}{}'.format(Url, count)
```

Also, you have an *infinite* loop since the value of `count` is never changed inside the loop. To fix this add

`count += 1`

at the bottom of your loop.

Answer (score 3):

Try casting count to a string as in

```
Url = "http://www.ihiphopmusic.com/music/page/" + str(count)
```

or use formatting

```
Url = "http://www.ihiphopmusic.com/music/page/%s" % count
```

or maybe even

```
Url = "http://www.ihiphopmusic.com/music/page/{count}".format(count=count)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

`url = "http://www.ihiphopmusic.com/music/page/"
while count < 20:
     '''You can redefine the variable
     Also, you have to convert count to a string as url is also a string'''
     url = url + str(count)
     print url`

Answer (score 1):

```
Url = "http://www.ihiphopmusic.com/music/page/%d" % (count,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the int to a string.

```
Url = (Url) + str(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the integer to a string

```
count = 0
while count < 20:
    Url = "http://www.ihiphopmusic.com/music/page/"
    Url = (Url) + str(count)     
    #Url = Url.append(count)     
    print Url
```